# How to insert values into multiple tables using a form having relation map using hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a registration form:

```
<form action="${ pageContext.request.contextPath }/customer/add" method="post">
<div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Address: </label>
    <input type="text" name="address.address">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
```

Here i want to insert value of this form into customer and address account having the following pojo:

**Cusotmer.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private Long id;
@Column
private String name;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;
```

**Address.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private Long id;
@Column
private String address;
```

I have created a daoImpl method to add customer and their respective address:

**CustomerDaoImpl**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addCustomer(Customer c) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(c);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

**AddressDaoImpl**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addAddress(Address a) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(a);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();        
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

@Autowired
private AddressDao addressDao;

@RequestMapping(value="/customer/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer c, @ModelAttribute Address a){
    addressDao.addAddress(a);
    c.setAddress(a);
    customerDao.addCustomer(c);
    return "redirect:/customer";
}
```

Insert operation not working for address value only. Customer is added along with the respective address_id but in address table itself, the address name is not inserted just id is created.

Comment: *not working*  means? Any error message?

Comment: Customer is added along with the address_id but in address table address is created but the form value is not saved. @Jens

Comment: It is not a good idea to use db entities in a frontend. You should use pojo's, which only stores plain data. An entity has many objects in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the private vairable address in the Address pojo so that it wont contrast with the address object in the Customer pojo.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
private Long id;
@Column
private String aName;    // change is here...
```

Similaly change the form address input name from **address.address** to **aName** only.

```
<form action="${ pageContext.request.contextPath }/customer/add" method="post">
<div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Address: </label>
    <input type="text" name="aName">    // see the change here...
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
```

And rest is same in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer c, @ModelAttribute Address a){
    addressDao.addAddress(a);
    c.setAddress(a);
    customerDao.addCustomer(c);
    return "redirect:/customer";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add cascade options so whenever a Customer is saved, the corresponding Address is Saved.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;
```

Simplify Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer c){
    customerDao.addCustomer(c);
    return "redirect:/customer";
```

}

Comment: didn't work...in form do i have to change the name of address input field or its ok to user address.address...@Alan Hay

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can help you with your problem, but can try to correct something.

1) `@Transactional` annotation is used on service layer, not DAO. And you actualy don't use both `@Transactional` annotation and `session.beginTransaction();`, choose one of them

2) You don't have to put the `@Column` annotation everytime, it's useless until you have to specify some properties in it.

```
@Column
private String name;
```

3) With spring controller you can use `@PostMapping`. More about here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Hope this can help, somehow.